# Mock only part of the return of a mocked function with jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Using jest and typescript, I wonder if that's possible to mock only a part of the return of a function. My goal is to pass a spy for the mocked part, and to receive the original function output for the unmocked part.

Given the following function, that I want to mock part of the return:

```js
// util.ts

export interface OutputMyFunction {
  function: void;
  anotherFunction: void;
}

export function myFunction(): OutputMyFunction {
  return {
    function: () => console.log('function!'); // ⬅️ I want to mock this function
    anotherFunction: () => console.log('another function!'); // I don't want to alter this function
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can mock `function` without altering what `anotherFunction` would have returned, without the mock?

```js
// myModule.test.ts

import {myFunction, OutputMyFunction} from '../util';

jest.mock('../util', () => ({
  myFunction: jest.fn(),
}));

const myFunctionMock: jest.Mock<() => OutputMyFunction> =
  jest.requireMock('../util').myFunction;

describe('myModule', () => {
  describe('when doing this', () => {
    it('should call `function`' () => {
      const functionSpy = jest.fn();

      // When mocking the return value of `function` using mockReturnValue, I should pass a mock for all other properties
      // Is there a way I can get the original value that myFunction would have returned, for all the other properties?
      myFunctionMock.mockReturnValue({
        function: functionSpy,
      });
    }) 
  }
});
```

The reason why other returned properties should have their real implementation, is that it would make it clearer what is the test case testing for.

Also in case the function is returning a complex object or has complex logic, it can be complicated to mock all properties in a way that matches what the original implementation would have returned.

Another approach would be to create two functions in the util file, with each one returning a different output so that it can be mocked separately. But I wonder if there is another approach that would work without having to refactor that file.

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here? Either `myFunction` is a _collaborator_, and mocking it out entirely is appropriate, or it's the thing you're trying to test and you shouldn't use a test double for any of it.

Comment: what I am trying to test is that a function part of the return of myFunction is executed in the correct scenario

Comment: And in that context why does the other function in that object need to have its real implementation? Please [edit] to give a [mre] and explain the scenario.

Comment: The reason for other properties to have their real implementation is that it makes it clearer what is the test case testing for. Also in case the function is returning a complex object, it would be complicated to mock all properties to make it like the original implementation. I edited the post

Comment: If those other properties aren't getting used, wouldn't the clearest scope be if the test double was just `{ function: jest.fn() }` so any access to e.g. `anotherFunction` would fail? But equally if consumers only need a subset of the properties, that suggests an [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) problem. With such an abstract example, it's hard to say what's really going on.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `requireActual` like this?

```
jest.mock('../util', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('../utils').myFunciton;

  return
  {
    myFunction: {...original(),function:jest.fn()}
  }
});
```